# Flex CSS property in <table> doesn't work on IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, flexbox

I'm looking for a solution how to make the Flex property work on a `table` component across all three browsers (IE, Firefox and Chrome).

The following code works only on Chrome (even though `-ms-` and `-webkit-` prefixes added):

```css
table {
  background-color: white;
}
.child {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 3px solid;
}
.container {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.child.one {
  color: green;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}
.child.two {
  color: purple;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  order: 2;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.child.three {
  color: red;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="container">
      <td class="child one" align="left">
        One
      </td>
      <td class="child two" align="center">
        Two.
        <br>Lorem ipsum
        <br>dolor sit amet
        <br>This is a bit longer line
      </td>
      <td class="child three" align="right">
        Three
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please look the code in fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ax961ys1/

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @nick I know it. But when i use it on `div` elements all works fine. So I guess, i'm doing something wrong with this table.

Comment: @werasquez For future reference, I've moved your entire code into a Stack Snippet as Stack Overflow requires full code to be in the question itself and not in an external location (such as JS Fiddle) just in case the link dies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would appear to be due to each `.child` element being `display: table-cell;` by default (expected as these are indeed table cells!).

In Chrome when you use the flexbox model on `.container` the `.child` elements are automatically converted into `display: block;` which enables flexbox to work.

[image: Chrome computed values]

In Firefox and IE the `.child` elements remain as `display: table-cell;`.

[image: Firefox computed values]

The latest W3C draft for the CSS Flexible Box Layout Module states:

> The display value of a flex item is blockified: if the specified display of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level equivalent. (See CSS2.1§9.7 [CSS21] and CSS Display [CSS3-DISPLAY] for details on this type of display value conversion.)

*Flex Items (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)*

This suggests that flex items should be changed to its [block-level equivalent](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) (if it isn't already a block-level element).

The draft goes further and states:

> Some values of display normally trigger the creation of anonymous boxes around the original box. If such a box is a flex item, it is blockified first, and so anonymous box creation will not happen. For example, two contiguous flex items with display: table-cell will become two separate display: block flex items, instead of being wrapped into a single anonymous table.

*Flex Items (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)*

In this instance it appears that this is something that Chrome is doing but IE and Firefox are not. The presence of the anonymous table and the fact that the `.child` elements are not blockified would seem to be the cause of the behaviour.

To obtain the same result in Chrome, IE and Firefox:

- Add `display: block;` to `.child`
- To ensure the `.child` elements wrap correctly in IE add `display: block;` to `table` and `tbody`

```css
table {
  background-color: white;
  display: block; /*Required for wrap to work correctly in IE*/
}
tbody {
  display: block; /*Required for wrap to work correctly in IE*/
}
.child {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 3px solid;
  display: block;
}
.container {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.child.one {
  color: green;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}
.child.two {
  color: purple;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  order: 2;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.child.three {
  color: red;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="container">
      <td class="child one" align="left">
        One
      </td>
      <td class="child two" align="center">
        Two.
        <br>Lorem ipsum
        <br>dolor sit amet
        <br>This is a bit longer line
      </td>
      <td class="child three" align="right">
        Three
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But still it doesn't work on IE (11). All columns should swap into rows when they dont have enought space.

Comment: @werasquez Looks like IE requires two further changes to get it working in the same way as FIrefox and Chrome. Please see the amendments made to my answer.

Comment: Great answer, but: "This suggests that flex items should be changed to its block-level equivalent (if it isn't already a block-level element). This is something that Chrome does but IE and Firefox do not." Maybe. but I don't think so. The flex-item of a flex container element that contains table-cells will be the anonymous table object generated to wrap the table-cells. Blockifying a table still makes a table and an anonymous table object will shrink-to-fit in the way that firefox and IE do. Only by setting the td elements to `display:block` makes the anonymous table objects not be generated.

Comment: @Alohci I think you are right that the anonymous table is having an effect in this instance, reading the draft a bit further it is possible that the behviour sits somewhere between our explanations as it goes on to say "Some values of display normally trigger the creation of anonymous boxes around the original box. If such a box is a flex item, it is blockified first, and so anonymous box creation will not happen.". So I think you are correct that the anonymous table object is being created in Firefox and IE even though the draft suggests it shouldn't and that the `td` should be blockified.

Comment: Ah. I see. Hmm, that directly contradicts what the earlier drafts said. Fair enough, I agree with you.

Comment: even with the above change, flex wrap does not seem to be working, right?

Comment: Hi @wallop any particular browser? Just tried in Chrome, IE and Firefox and they all seem to wrap at the expected time.

Comment: Interesting, I tried chrome, will try again and get back