# Flex wrap within tbody IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Flex wrap is not working within `tbody` of a table in IE 11. I tried different suggestions from other stack overflow posts but none of them were useful.

If you open this URL in chrome/firefox/edge you can see flex wrap working fine but in IE 11 or so it doesn't 
https://liveweave.com/j2yzx0

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451371/flex-css-property-in-table-doesnt-work-on-ie-and-firefox) as reference too but not of much use.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 26%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>R1C1</td>
      <td>R1C2</td>
      <td>R1C3</td>
      <td>R1C4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R2C1</td>
      <td>R2C2</td>
      <td>R2C3</td>
      <td>R2C4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I even tried adding display block, -ms- prefix etc but to no avail
Link here: https://liveweave.com/Liylfz

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table,
tbody,
thead,
td,
th {
  display: block;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

thead,
tbody {
  display: block;
}

tr {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 50%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>R1C1</td>
      <td>R1C2</td>
      <td>R1C3</td>
      <td>R1C4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R2C1</td>
      <td>R2C2</td>
      <td>R2C3</td>
      <td>R2C4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Using float: left seem to help but still it appears none of the flex properties are working since setting flex order using order is not working.

Answer (score 2):

In IE11, when *flex items* have `table-cell` as their *display*, it doesn't get *blockified* to `display: block` as it does normally in Chrome or Firefox. You can verify this by looking at the *computed styles* in the Developer Tools after inspecting the `th` or `td` elements here.

Just add `display: block` to `th,td` here - see demo below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 26%;
  display: block; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>R1C1</td>
      <td>R1C2</td>
      <td>R1C3</td>
      <td>R1C4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R2C1</td>
      <td>R2C2</td>
      <td>R2C3</td>
      <td>R2C4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I had already tried it before and I tried it again, it didn work unfortunately

Comment: I don't know why its not working in the *liveweave*, but in the snippet above and in [this fiddle too](https://jsfiddle.net/crujpo76/) it works in IE11

Comment: you are right. It seems to be working in IE11 in the above code snippet.

Comment: I will run some tests to see if it is issue with liveweave or some particular case and then will make the answer : )
Thank you